# How do I quit a window in tkinter without quitting program?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, command, quit

I would like the second 'Enter' button to allow the user to quit from this window. What is the command? I believe self.quit quits everything but the command I've used doesn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Enter_Name_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text= "Please enter your name and class." )
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        enter_name = Entry(self)
        enter_name.pack()
        enter_name.focus_set()


        def callback():
            self.display_name = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text = "Now please enter your tutor group.")
            self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            tutor = Entry(self)
            tutor.pack()
            tutor.focus_set()
            Enter_0.config(state="disabled")

            Enter_0_2 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=Enter_Name_Window.quit)
            Enter_0_2.pack()

        Enter_0 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=callback)
        Enter_0.pack()
```

Comment: Your code formatting is messed up, making it hard to read the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "quit from this window"? Are you asking how to destroy the window, or just hide it?

Answer (score 1):

There were a lot of bugs to begin with and most notably:

```
command=Enter_Name_Window.quit
```

should be

```
command=self.destroy
```

Refrain from using the `quit()` method as its unstable and pass the class instance `self` instead of a new class object

Anywhere here's your revamped code:

```
class Enter_Name_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.text = tk.Label(self.parent, width=40, height=2, text= "Please enter your name and class." )
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        enter_name = tk.Entry(self)
        enter_name.pack()
        enter_name.focus_set()


        def callback():
            self.display_name = tk.Label(self.parent, width=40, height=2, text = "Now please enter your tutor group.")
            self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            tutor = tk.Entry(self.parent)
            tutor.pack()
            tutor.focus_set()
            Enter_0.config(state="disabled")

            Enter_0_2 = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Enter", width=10, command=self.destroy)
            Enter_0_2.pack()

        Enter_0 = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Enter", width=10, command=callback)
        Enter_0.pack()
```